# How to read a Table in a PDF using iText java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I dont have much idea on pdf processing using java.I want to read a table in a PDF file using the iText java library. How to proceed?

Comment: It would actually help if you would specify your question, add some sourcecode of what you have done already and what you have tried that did not work so far.

Comment: I dont have much idea on pdf processing using java.i have used the command line(java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar ExtractText [OPTIONS] <PDF file> [Text file]) to convert pdf into some format from which i can process the table.Also i have used the code in http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/itext/convertpdfToTextFile.html .

Answer (score 7):

> You can extract text from a content stream, but for ordinary PDFs, the result will be plain text (without any structure). If there's a table on the page, that table won't be recognized as such. You'll get the content and some white space, but that's not a tabular structure! Only if you have a tagged PDF, you can obtain an XML-file. If the PDF contains tags that are recognized as table tags, this will be reflected in the PDF.

That's what I found out [here](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/27)

Comment: @soumitra still no solution?

Answer (score 1):

For reading content of the table from a PDF file, you only have to convert the PDF into a text file by using any API (I have used `PdfTextExtracter.getTextFromPage()` of iText) and then read that txt file by your Java program. After reading it the major task is done. You have to filter the data that you need, which you can do by continuously using split method of `String` class until you find the record you want.

Below is my code in which I have extracted part of the record from a PDF file and written it into a .CSV file. You can view the PDF file here: http://www.cea.nic.in/reports/monthly/generation_rep/actual/jan13/opm_02.pdf

```
public static void genrateCsvMonth_Region(String pdfpath, String csvpath) {
        try {
            String line = null;
            // Appending Header in CSV file...
            BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvpath,
                    true));
            writer1.close();
            // Checking whether file is empty or not..
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvpath));
                         if ((line = br.readLine()) == null) {
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                        csvpath, true));
                writer.append("REGION,");
                writer.append("YEAR,");
                writer.append("MONTH,");
                writer.append("THERMAL,");
                writer.append("NUCLEAR,");
                writer.append("HYDRO,");
                writer.append("TOTAL\n");
                writer.close();
            }
            // Reading the pdf file..
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfpath);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvpath,
                    true));

            // Extracting records from page into String..
            String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
            // Extracting month and Year from String..
            String period1[] = page.split("PEROID");
            String period2[] = period1[0].split(":");
            String month[] = period2[1].split("-");
            String period3[] = month[1].split("ENERGY");
            String year[] = period3[0].split("VIS");

            // Extracting Northen region
            String northen[] = page.split("NORTHEN REGION");
            String nthermal1[] = northen[0].split("THERMAL");
            String nthermal2[] = nthermal1[1].split(" ");

            String nnuclear1[] = northen[0].split("NUCLEAR");
            String nnuclear2[] = nnuclear1[1].split(" ");

            String nhydro1[] = northen[0].split("HYDRO");
            String nhydro2[] = nhydro1[1].split(" ");

            String ntotal1[] = northen[0].split("TOTAL");
            String ntotal2[] = ntotal1[1].split(" ");

            // Appending filtered data into CSV file..
            writer.append("NORTHEN" + ",");
            writer.append(year[0] + ",");
            writer.append(month[0] + ",");
            writer.append(nthermal2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(nnuclear2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(nhydro2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(ntotal2[4] + "\n");

            // Extracting Western region
            String western[] = page.split("WESTERN");

            String wthermal1[] = western[1].split("THERMAL");
            String wthermal2[] = wthermal1[1].split(" ");

            String wnuclear1[] = western[1].split("NUCLEAR");
            String wnuclear2[] = wnuclear1[1].split(" ");

            String whydro1[] = western[1].split("HYDRO");
            String whydro2[] = whydro1[1].split(" ");

            String wtotal1[] = western[1].split("TOTAL");
            String wtotal2[] = wtotal1[1].split(" ");

            // Appending filtered data into CSV file..
            writer.append("WESTERN" + ",");
            writer.append(year[0] + ",");
            writer.append(month[0] + ",");
            writer.append(wthermal2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(wnuclear2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(whydro2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(wtotal2[4] + "\n");

            // Extracting Southern Region
            String southern[] = page.split("SOUTHERN");

            String sthermal1[] = southern[1].split("THERMAL");
            String sthermal2[] = sthermal1[1].split(" ");

            String snuclear1[] = southern[1].split("NUCLEAR");
            String snuclear2[] = snuclear1[1].split(" ");

            String shydro1[] = southern[1].split("HYDRO");
            String shydro2[] = shydro1[1].split(" ");

            String stotal1[] = southern[1].split("TOTAL");
            String stotal2[] = stotal1[1].split(" ");

            // Appending filtered data into CSV file..
            writer.append("SOUTHERN" + ",");
            writer.append(year[0] + ",");
            writer.append(month[0] + ",");
            writer.append(sthermal2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(snuclear2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(shydro2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(stotal2[4] + "\n");

            // Extracting eastern region
            String eastern[] = page.split("EASTERN");

            String ethermal1[] = eastern[1].split("THERMAL");
            String ethermal2[] = ethermal1[1].split(" ");

            String ehydro1[] = eastern[1].split("HYDRO");
            String ehydro2[] = ehydro1[1].split(" ");

            String etotal1[] = eastern[1].split("TOTAL");
            String etotal2[] = etotal1[1].split(" ");
            // Appending filtered data into CSV file..
            writer.append("EASTERN" + ",");
            writer.append(year[0] + ",");
            writer.append(month[0] + ",");
            writer.append(ethermal2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(" " + ",");
            writer.append(ehydro2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(etotal2[4] + "\n");

            // Extracting northernEastern region
            String neestern[] = page.split("NORTH");

            String nethermal1[] = neestern[2].split("THERMAL");
            String nethermal2[] = nethermal1[1].split(" ");

            String nehydro1[] = neestern[2].split("HYDRO");
            String nehydro2[] = nehydro1[1].split(" ");

            String netotal1[] = neestern[2].split("TOTAL");
            String netotal2[] = netotal1[1].split(" ");

            writer.append("NORTH EASTERN" + ",");
            writer.append(year[0] + ",");
            writer.append(month[0] + ",");
            writer.append(nethermal2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(" " + ",");
            writer.append(nehydro2[4] + ",");
            writer.append(netotal2[4] + "\n");
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

My Solution

```
package com.geek.tutorial.itext.table;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;

public class SimplePDFTable
{
    public SimplePDFTable() throws Exception
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, 
            new FileOutputStream("SimplePDFTable.pdf"));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2); // Code 1
        // Code 2
        table.addCell("1");
        table.addCell("2");
        // Code 3
        table.addCell("3");
        table.addCell("4");
        // Code 4
        table.addCell("5");
        table.addCell("6");
        // Code 5
        document.add(table);        
        document.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        try
        {
            SimplePDFTable pdfTable = new SimplePDFTable();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: vijaykamma this code is for writing tables in pdf...i want to read a pdf table