# How to determine if PDF is tagged or not?

Tags: android, pdf

How will I know if PDF is tagged or not? I'm developing a program that would copy a text inside a PDF file and display it in my app, so I tried to test the PDF file, I copied a table from a PDF file (Ordinary Copy+Paste) and paste it in MS Word. The result was a normal text without tables. There are some issues that when you copy a table from a pdf file and paste it to Word it becomes an **image**. Is that true?

Comment: Whether or not text that is copied from a PDF can be pasted as a table depends on the program that you are using to view/copy the PDF and the program that you are pasting into. 

The PDF may have the text as a table, but the viewer is transforming it into plain text when you copy from it. Alternatively, the program you are pasting it into may be converting it into plain text when you are pasting it.

Comment: ah so it depends on how it will be copied? im planning on using a API for reading a PDF file and im developing my app in android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to determine if PDF is tagged or not?

Depending on the library you are using to process your files, you could try to retrieve the entry `MarkInfo` from the `Catalog` dictionary.

From the PDF Specification:

> **TABLE 3.25 Entries in the catalog dictionary**
>   **KEY:** MarkInfo
>   **TYPE:** dictionary
>   **VALUE:** (Optional; PDF 1.4) A mark information dictionary containing information about the document’s usage of Tagged PDF
>   conventions (see Section 10.6, “Logical Structure”).

However, even if the value of this property is set to TRUE, it does not mean that the tags will actually be there, and if they are, they might not be usefull to you at all for extracting tables. You can still find PDF files with tables that use the tags only for marking paragraphs and pictures.

Long story short, unless *you* are generating the files that your application is going to consume, so that you can know which tags to look for, it is **not** a good idea to rely on these tags for "tables extraction from PDF".

Answer (score 1):

I found a comment to a different question which seems to have answered this.

[How to read a Table in a PDF using iText java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878695/how-to-read-a-table-in-a-pdf-using-itext-java#comment14421183_10878783)

> You can extract text from a content stream, but for ordinary PDFs, the result will be plain text (without any structure). If there's a table on the page, that table won't be recognized as such. You'll get the content and some white space, but that's not a tabular structure! Only if you have a tagged PDF, you can obtain an XML-file. If the PDF contains tags that are recognized as table tags, this will be reflected in the PDF.

This is from http://support.itextpdf.com/node/27

Comment: oh. so even using a normal extraction from PDF to program it would only be text form. even it is displayed?

Comment: It would be in table form only if the PDF was tagged and could be converted to xml.